# what 3dplot software to use to create these images

Tags: math-software

Could you please tell me what software/program did the creator of these graphs use? Should I ask this in $\TeX/\LaTeX$ community?

[image][image]

Comment: I don't know about the *specific* software, but all major 3D plotting routines will do that.

Comment: Unless you created these images (which seems unlikely given your question), a citation for the source of these images is needed.

Comment: Mathematica is useful but it is costly. For free I recommend Geogebra. Actually the images are beautiful because of the gradient of the colors.